# Table under table in excel by sas

Tags: excel, sas

How can I generate on sas a table under a table on excel? I try to explain better my problem. I have to run a procedure every week. This procedure generate to me a table that I have to copy and past on excel. The sequent week I run and I copy and past the new table gained under the last one so I can directly see if the results are ok. My point is, exist a way to do it directly writing a proc or something and without copying and pasting every time? The important is to gain those tables in the same sheet. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A read of the ODS EXCEL documentation will reveal `OPTIONS(<suboptions>)`.  You want to use `ODS EXCEL … OPTIONS(SHEET_INTERVAL="NONE")`

> (SHEET_INTERVAL= 'BYGROUP' | 'PAGE'| 'PROC' | 'NONE' | ‘TABLE’)
>   specifies the criteria for when a new worksheet is created.
>
> BYGROUP
>   creates a new worksheet after each BYGROUP.
>
> NONE
>   creates one worksheet with all of the data.
>
> PAGE
>   creates a worksheet for each page of procedure output.
>
> PROC
>   creates a worksheet of all of the procedure output.
>
> TABLE
>   creates a worksheet for each table.